# Tableview with two filter in javafx2.2

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have created a `Tableview` with multiple columns, I would like to add two filters to sort the data in the `Tableview` but i don't know how it is write this in `javafx`.

Comment: Thanks for editing  Mr gaige

Comment: Filtering and sorting are two different things, please update your question to provide more detail on what you wish to do.  You might want to look at the [TiwulFX](http://tiwulfx.panemu.com/demo/) demo and see if their enhanced `TableView` control does what you want.